# HFSPlus unable to load nls for utf8

Tags: arch-linux, mount, hfs+

I'm trying to mount a .img file created from dmg2img. I have tried the following:

```
sudo modprobe hfsplus
sudo mount -o loop -t hfsplus ./path/to/img /mnt/iso
```

This gives me an error:

```
mount: /mnt/iso: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop9, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
```

I have tracked the error down to HFSPlus giving this error from dmesg:

```
hfsplus: unable to load nls for utf8
```

a quick google search finds only one relevant result, an [RFC patch](https://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/2108.1/00199.html) in which it says `NLS table for utf8 is broken and cannot be fixed.`

How do i get this to work?

I use arch btw

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when the partition type of an hfsplus partition was set to a non-Apple filesystem.

Check if the type id of the partition is something by Apple.

`fdisk /dev/sdX` then press `i` and select the partition. If the `Type` field  doesn't contain "Apple" or "Apple boot" , press t and change the type id to 144 or 149.

(`/dev/sdX` is the drive that contains your hfs partition)